# Import issues with Python and celery

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery

There is a pretty strange issue happening on my production server that doesn't come up in UAT or my development environment. Stack setup is Ubuntu 14LTS, Apache2, Python 2.7,Celery, RabbitMQ, Django 1.6.

How it works is that there is an async task that is called whenever an excel report needs to be generated. Depending on the type of company, a different report is created and emailed to the logged in user. The functions to create the different reports are all placed in a file called report_lib.py and they are not importing from any other app. The code goes like this:

```
            if policies.carrier == "class_one":
                report_lib.create_remittance_class_one_report(company_id)
            else:
                report_lib.create_generic_remittance_report(company_id)
```

Get this, the first conditional works no problem. The second conditional works when I don't have a company type set(works as expected), but for any other class it fails with the following error:

```
[2014-10-27 17:56:55,271: WARNING/Worker-1] There was an error: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_generic_remittance_report'
```

To make things more interesting I removed the conditional and defaulted to the code just calling the "create_generic_remittance_report" function for all cases, which works without complaining about that module.

I'm 99% sure that there are no-circular references. Oh, and the library being referenced is under the only app being used in the django project. Could this be a compiler caching issue?
Has anyone come across a similar issue using the same setup?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the function being referenced was indented an extra tab. I guess since celery only calls it, it came back with that error.